# Why does clicking the div check the hidden radio button?

Tags: html, css, radio-button, label, hidden

The following CSS / HTML works exactly as I want but I don't know why.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
input[type=radio] { display: none }
label > div { background: yellow }
label > div:hover { background: pink }
input[type=radio]:checked + div { background: red }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<label><input type="radio" name="r"><div>one</div></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="r"><div>two</div></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="r"><div>three</div></label>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried three browsers and they all accept a click anywhere within the div to check its hidden radio button.

Can anybody explain this very useful but perhaps undocumented quirk?

Answer (score 3):

I have just found the answer to my own question.

It is because clicking within 'label' controls the radio button. See: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

I will leave this question here because others may find this relatively frugal code useful.

Answer (score 2):

In you code, you have a hidden  element that won't show up but it still gives you option to click. And you also have a  element that extends all the way from left to right. And you have them both inside a  element. When you place the radio button and div inside the label, the size of  element extends from left to right because of  element and it also gets a clickable option since it has radio(hidden) inside it. I hope this answers your question.